# Проблема с обращениями к массиву в объекте JS

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста
Есть массив с объектами внутри, в объектах есть строчные значения и массив с числами
Необходимо создать цикл для массива с числами через функцию. Как указать массив 'marks' для всех объектов с общего массива во входной параметр функции?

Код:

```
var students = [
    person1 = {
        firstName: 'Александр',
        lastName : 'Иванчук',
        group: 'T993',
        marks: [2,4,4,5,2,3,3,4,5,3,2,4,3]
    },
    person2 = {
        firstName: 'Анатолий',
        lastName : 'Косанов',
        group: 'T993',
        marks: [3,4,5,4,4,1,4,3,4,4,4,3,5]
    },
    person3 = {
        firstName: 'Руслан',
        lastName : 'Столбов',
        group: 'T993',
        marks: [3,3,5,4,4,1,4,4,3,5,4,4,4]
    },
    person4 = {
        firstName: 'Иван',
        lastName : 'Пробкин',
        group: 'T994',
        marks: [2,3,2,1,2,3,2,3,3,3,4,1,1]
    },
    person5 = {
        firstName: 'Владислав',
        lastName : 'Голубев',
        group: 'T994',
        marks: [1,2,2,2,3,2,2,3,5,1,2,3,2]
    }
]


function fullName(object){
    var names = object.firstName + object.lastName;
    return(names);
    console.log(names)
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как указать массив 'marks' для всех объектов с общего массива во входной параметр функции?

Вы ведь передаёте в функцию весь массив с объектами. И можете потом делать с его содержимым, всё, что решите. Вам будет очень неудобно работать с каждым свойством объекта по отдельности. Представьте, что у объекта, будет 200 св-в, а что-то делать, нужно будет с половиной из них.

```js
var students = [
    person1 = {
        firstName: 'Александр',
        lastName : 'Иванчук',
        group: 'T993',
        marks: [2,4,4,5,2,3,3,4,5,3,2,4,3]
    },
    person2 = {
        firstName: 'Анатолий',
        lastName : 'Косанов',
        group: 'T993',
        marks: [3,4,5,4,4,1,4,3,4,4,4,3,5]
    },
    person3 = {
        firstName: 'Руслан',
        lastName : 'Столбов',
        group: 'T993',
        marks: [3,3,5,4,4,1,4,4,3,5,4,4,4]
    },
    person4 = {
        firstName: 'Иван',
        lastName : 'Пробкин',
        group: 'T994',
        marks: [2,3,2,1,2,3,2,3,3,3,4,1,1]
    },
    person5 = {
        firstName: 'Владислав',
        lastName : 'Голубев',
        group: 'T994',
        marks: [1,2,2,2,3,2,2,3,5,1,2,3,2]
    }
]

function fullName(object){
    let names = object.map(val => `${val.firstName} ${val.lastName}`)
    let marks = object.map(val => val.marks)
    return {names, marks};
   
}

console.log(fullName(students))
```